# How can I make images respect their div boundries?

Tags: css, html, image, center

Here's the JSFiddle (disregard the differences with picture below):

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/y2PhX/

I'm supposed to have something like this in the white background, but the images in the center and right column seem to expand outside of their domain.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to cleanly handle this situation? It needs to be nice and centered, needs to end up like the picture, I feel I'm close but can't quite get there. Thank you, learning quite a lot in this tag area in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pixel widths, not percentage.

Comment: On the inner elements that contain the pictures. Unless you're building flexible layouts, stick to pixel measurements.